# how to set the "Color.rgb" in Java to random?

Tags: java, random

I'm experimenting with Android studio and I want to pass random values to the `Color.rgb`. This is the code that I tried

```java
int x  = rand.nextInt(9);
int y  = rand.nextInt(9);
int z  = rand.nextInt(9);

viewTest.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(x,y,z));
```

edit:
the color range is between 0 and 255 so the right code is

```java
int x  = rand.nextInt(256);
int y  = rand.nextInt(256);
int z  = rand.nextInt(256);

viewTest.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(x,y,z));
```

not the best solution but it works
Thanks to [jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for reminding me :)

Comment: Okay, that code looks fine - although it will be close to black as you're only asking for values between 0 and 8 inclusive, when the full range is 0 to 255 inclusive. So I'd expect you to see random nearly-black background colours. What's actually happening, compared with what you expected to happen?

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah that's actually right , thank you,  i'm too tired and forgot that the color range is between 0 and 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random color like this:

```java
Random rng = new Random();
int red = rng.nextInt(256);
int green = rng.nextInt(256);
int blue = rng.nextInt(256);

viewTest.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
```

Using `nextInt(256)` means that you will get a random `int` from 0 to 255.